# проблема с notification отрабатывает рандомно

Tags: android, background-task

Есть проблема с notification, иногда отрабатывают нормально, иногда через день или два. По плану они должны отрабатывать 2 раза  в день в 8 утра и 6 вечера.

По логам(log кастомизированый лог который пишет и на консоль и в базу sqllite) 
в schedule отдается верное время. Если я запускаю для теста и ставлю, например запустить через 5 минут, то отрабатывает всегда.

Возможно за несколько часов ожидания такск умирает? Как можно проверить жив ли он? Или возможно данный метод не подходит для долгосрочных планов?
Указанный код запускается в сервисе. Который стартует либо при включении телефона или при старте программы.

```
mTimer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task1 = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.log("service", "Schedule morning done");
                isRunNote();
            }
        };
        TimerTask task2 = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.log("service", "Schedule evening done");
                isRunNote();
            }
        };
        Date date1, date2;
        date1 = DateLab.nowDayPlusHour(8); //возращает Date если сегодня больше чем 8 часов, то вернет "Завтра 8 утра"
        date2 = DateLab.nowDayPlusHour(18);
        log.log("service", "Schedule morning" + date1.toString());
        mTimer.schedule(task1, date1, DateLab.HMs(24));//DateLab.HMs(x) возвращает количество миллисекунд в X часах
        log.log("service", "Schedule evening" + date2.toString());
        mTimer.schedule(task2, date2, DateLab.HMs(24));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timer` работает только пока Ваше приложение работает, естественно за несколько дней нахождения в бэкграунде система завершает приложение за ненадобностью. Вместо этого необходимо использовать `AlarmManager`, который будет запускать подготовленный Вами `Intent` по расписанию, а вы уже обрабатывать его запуск в `BroadcastReceiver`. [Вот здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) есть официальный гайд по созданию периодически повторяющихся задач.

Начиная с Android 5 (API 21) также доступен класс `JobScheduler`, который позволяет также планировать периодические задачи, но с учётом различных факторов и с более рациональным расходом батареи и ресурсов девайса. Небольшой пример работы с ним есть [тут](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-job-scheduling-with-android-job-4a2c020b9742).

**UPD:** Ещё есть библиотека [Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job), которая,судя по всему, использует единый интерфейс для создания периодических задач, используя `JobScheduler` или `AlarmManager` в зависимости от версии ОС. Увы, не использовал и не могу поделиться опытом работы. Что-то похожее есть и в библиотеке [Trigger](https://github.com/airk000/Trigger), но она больше ориентированна на запуск задач по совокупности каких-то условий, нежели просто для периодических задач.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Забыл, написать что данный код я запускаю в сервисе. он же не должен убиваться? 
Про JobScheduler читал, но мне нужна поддержка от Api16

Comment: Нет, сервисы тоже не бесконечные и система вольна их завершать, в Android 8 это, кстати, ещё больше ужесточили. Только foreground сервисы работают "вечно", но для них нужно явно показывать нотификацию. Плюс, постоянно работающий сервис потребляет ресурсы и батарею, поэтому лучше использовать `AlarmManager`, если нужна поддержка старых версий. Ещё есть библиотека https://github.com/evernote/android-job, которая судя по всему работает с единым API на новых девайсах поверх `JobScheduler`, а на старых с `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Спасибо большое